# Lua: read a file

Tags: lua

I am using lua to read the data in file, and this code is shown as below,

```
   filename = "./temp/vtx_vel"..id..".dat"
   file = io.open(filename, "r")   
   lineno = i + ni*j
   local n = -1
   for l in io.lines(filename) do
       n = n + 1
       if n == lineno then 
          vel = tonumber(l)
          break
       end
   end
   file:close()
```

The data in the external file is changing. However, it's quite strange to me that I got the same value when reading this file at different steps. Why is that?

Thank you.

Comment: You aren't reading from the file handle you've opened. You are opening a new handle in the `io.lines` call and never closing them. Use `file:lines()` in your loop and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed into "for l in file.lines() do", but got error: udf-vtx.lua:35: bad argument #1 to 'lines' (FILE* expected, got no value)

Comment: `file:lines()` not `file.lines()`. You need to call it as a "method" of the file (implicitly pass `file` as the first argument to the function).

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How so? Same unchanging data problem? Something else?

Comment: Yes, the data is still the initial data, even though the data in the external file has changed.

Comment: You are sure the file at that path is the one changing? You are calling that read function again multiple times and checking `vel` after each call and it isn't changing? Your line count is supposed to start from 0 (instead of 1)?

Comment: Yes, the file at that path is changing, it is determined by another function, and I can see this change. The lua script is to read this "vel" value and supply it to another code, and I output this "vel" value reading via lua, it's unchanged. The line count from code is from 0.

Comment: The only other things I can think of offhand are to check `lineno` and make sure that has the correct value (too high and you'll never update `vel`). If you print out the lines as that function sees them do you see the correct updated file contents (assuming other lines in the file have also changed)?

Comment: Is the data in the file changing or is the file at that path being overwritten? You may want to check that the inode numbers for the file stays the same as lua could have an older copy of the file open.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to read a file from my experience is to just do this:

```
local f = io.open(--your file here)
local output = {}
for each in f:lines() do
  output[#output+1] = each
end
```

Your file will be read into the table `output`.
Something else to note, unless you define a mode, `io.open()` opens a file by default in "r" or read mode.